# Select a node the sibling of which has a specific child

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<multistatus
xmlns="DAV:">
<response>
    <href>/1437425399/carddavhome/</href>
    <propstat>
        <prop>
            <resourcetype>
                <collection/>
            </resourcetype>
        </prop>
        <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
</response>
<response>
    <href>/1437425399/carddavhome/card/</href>
    <propstat>
        <prop>
            <resourcetype>
                <addressbook
                    xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"/>
                    <collection/>
                </resourcetype>
            </prop>
            <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
        </propstat>
    </response>
</multistatus>
```

I want to select the < href > /1437425399/carddavhome/card/< /href > whose sibling < propstat > has the < addressbook > child element.

I tried the following:

```
XNamespace nsdav = "DAV:";
XNamespace nscd = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav";
var hrefs = from response in root.Elements(nsdav + "response")
            where response.Elements(nscd + "addressbook") != null
            select response.Element(nsdav + "href");
```

and

```
var hrefs = from response in root.Elements(nsdav + "response")
            where response.Elements(nscd + "addressbook").Count() > 0
            select response.Element(nsdav + "href");
```

and

```
var hrefs = (from href in root.Descendants(nsdav + "href")
            where href.Parent.Elements(nscd + "addressbook").Count() > 0
            select href.Ancestors()).First()
```

and maybe some other similar logic but can't get the result that I am looking for. Where am I going wrong?

I am either getting both the < response > tags in the final result or none. I want to be able to select just the one node.

**EDIT
I won't know in advance the text within < href > I want to select. Only thing I know is that I have to select the text of the < href > whose sibling has the < addressbook > node as its child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. My main problem was checking for existence of a particular child element and I was using null and count for that. However, linq to xml doesn't work that way. To check for existence of an element, you have to use "Any" like so:

```
var hrefs = from response in root.Elements(nsdav + "response")
            where 
                 (from addressbook in response.Descendants(nscd + "addressbook")
                 select addressbook)
                 .Any()
            select response.Element(nsdav + "href").Value;
```

And this is how I got the result I wanted.

Comment: `root.Descendants(nsdav + "response")` also works in the first line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code

```
public static XmlNode SelectXmlNode()
    {
        XmlNode addNode=null;
        string xmlString = "*xmlString*"
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        var node = doc.ChildNodes;
        var siblings = node[0].NextSibling.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode cnode in siblings)
        {
                var childnode = cnode.ChildNodes[0].NextSibling.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].FirstChild;
                if (childnode.Name == "addressbook")
                {
                    addNode = cnode.ChildNodes[0];
                }  

        }

        return addNode;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is, I won't know in advance the text within < href > tag that I want to select. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: ok akshay, once you update your question, i will try to help on the same.

Comment: I think your answer is also correct. But I wanted to use linq-to-xml framework as the question was tagged.